# Grouping data and creating dictionary out of large data matrix fast

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, dataset

I have a data matrix where rows are observations and columns are features.

I have four features: 
(1) year of the observation, 
(2) name of a firm, 
(3) name of a given parameter associated with the firm,
(4) the value of that parameter.

E.g.

```
2015  firm1  debt    100
2015  firm1  equity  50
2015  firm1  debt    10
2014  firm2  debt    40
2014  firm1  equity  10
```

I want to group data like this:

```
{2015: {firm1: [110, 50], firm2: [0, 0]}, 2014: {firm1: [0, 10], firm2: [40, 0]}}
```

Or something similar, that would allow the same level of organisation of the data.

I have a way that is working, but it is taking too much time as it uses for loops. I have 600k rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered pandas?

Comment: I started out using pandas, but that seems to make it even slower.